# Mocking JDBC's Connection#prepareStatement always returns null with jMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc, testng, jmockit

I am trying to test JDBC calls to Oracle DB with jMockit. I have tried to simulate JDBC's `Connection#prepareStatement(String sql)` to return PreparedStatement mock object, but I only get a null value instead. My aim is to mock Connection APIs to return a mock PreparedStatement object, and to mock PreparedStatement APIs to return a mock ResultSet object.

My source code is given below.

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);) {
  try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
         "SELECT firstName, lastName from Employee where empId = ?");) {
    ps.setString(1, empId); // This is an input to function.
    try(ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();) {
      while(rs.next()) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
        emp.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
        return emp;
      }
    }
  }
}
return employees;
```

When I invoke

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
             "SELECT firstName, lastName from Employee where empId = ?")
```

My unit test is as follows

```
@Test()
  public void testQueryOutOfDateSpanishContent_Success(
      @Mocked final Connection connection, @Mocked final PreparedStatement ps) throws Exception {
    new Expectations(DriverManager.class) {
      {
        DriverManager.getConnection(
            dcrParameters.getEnvironmentUrl(), dcrParameters.getUsername(),
            dcrParameters.getPassword());
        result = connection;

        connection.prepareStatement(anyString);
        result = with(new Delegate<PreparedStatement>() {
          public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) throws SQLException {
            return ps;
          }
        });
      }
    };
    // Call the source function here.
```

I am using TestNG 6.10 with latest version of jMockit release. I am running the unit test with TestNG eclipse plugin. I am passing `-javaagent:C:\downloads\jmockit.jar`as a VM argument in Eclipse.

Update: The method accepts two mocked arguments that are provided by jMockit. If I don't pass the java agent, TestNG throws an error expecting the arguments to be passed through TestNG's dataProvider functionality. 
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

It does return a mock object, but it resorts to default behaviour. For example, I want to capture what value is being passed to  `ps.setString(1, empId)` or to simulate `rs.next()` to return true. But only default outputs are returned.

Comment: no exception you got during execution ? I think you should use a `Catch` block and try to print the `stackTrace` this situation must throw an exception. Thanxx

Comment: Connection#prepareStatement does not throw any Exception. The value is always null. The next statement ps.setString(1, empId);  throws NPE. So the problem is that null value is returned.

Comment: Why are you using a `Delegate` if it simply returns `ps`? Just use it directly  as the desired `result`, as done for `connection`. And note that methods like `with(...)` are meant for *parameter matching*, not for expectation results.

Comment: Also, there is no need to specify the `-javaagent` JVM parameter.

Comment: @Rogério I have tried to answer your questions in the updated section of the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. It's a feature :)

You need to configure the mock. By default they will return null.

You need to add 'Expectation'-s, as you can see on http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html

Comment: I have done that. Mocks are being created, but it is not being passed unless I set up two separate Expectation blocks.

Comment: That is a dangerous link. Please don't click on it